# How prove this definition $a\oplus b=a+b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, contest-math

Define $\oplus$: if for any real numbers $a,b,c$  there have
$$\left(a\oplus b\right)\oplus c=a+b+c$$

show that
$$a\oplus b=a+b$$

Comment: what had you tried?

Answer (score 13):

Let $k =0\oplus 0$.

Since $(0\oplus 0)\oplus c=c$ we see that $k\oplus c=c$ for each $c$, so $k$ is left neutral.

Next we see that $\oplus $ is commutative: 
$$b\oplus c=(k\oplus b)\oplus c=k+b+c=k+c+b=(k\oplus c)\oplus b=c\oplus b$$

Now we see that $k=0$:
$$(a\oplus k)\oplus k=a+2k \Rightarrow a=a+2k \Rightarrow k=0 $$

So $$a+b=a+b+0=(a\oplus b)\oplus 0=a\oplus b$$

Comment: $(0\oplus 0)\oplus c=0+0+c=c$

Comment: I just picked $1$ for the neutral element and I chose for $\oplus$ to be the multiplication operator. Your answer works, does it not.

Comment: You mean you observed $(a\odot b)\odot c= a\cdot b\cdot c$?

Comment: Yes. But why would I use another notation? The only thing that I wanted t say was that there were two answers: $+$ and $\cdot$ with the choice of $0$ and $1$, respectively.

Comment: So, your answer (1 up by me) could be improved by mentioning the other possibility if you agree.

Comment: @zoli By assumption we have $(a \oplus b)\oplus c=a+b+c$. How do you argument that the expression $(1 \oplus 1) \oplus c=1+1+c=2+c$ is equal to $c$? I don't see that.

Comment: @MarvinF: Where is that assumption stated?

Comment: @zoli $\oplus$ is defined like this in the original question.